# The correct way of using perfect tense

Tags: grammar

My question is about I wanna say to anyone about - i have not take shower for three days. What will be the correct form?

- I have not taken shower since three days.
- I didn’t take shower for three days.

Comment: Don't stand too close to me when you say that!

Comment: Please don't use wanna, gonna, etc. This is only suitable for very informal communication. Please also always capitalise the first person pronoun "I".

Answer (score 3):

You said it yourself. The correct form is:

> I have not taken a shower for three days.

This would be the correct form using Present Perfect.

"I **didn't** take a shower for three days" uses Past Simple, not Present Perfect. And

> I have not taken a shower since three days.

Would be incorrect, because "since" should indicate some time point or event, and not  duration ("three days").

Comment: It should be, I have not taken ***a*** shower.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  Also, have not had a shower. Although they mean the same thing, "to take a shower" is [especially used in AmE](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shower_1?q=shower).

Answer (score 2):

I have not taken **a** shower for three days.

Answer (score 1):

First sentence is required to be corrected slightly like:

> I have not taken **a** shower **for** three days.

If you structure the sentence with **since** you have to indicate a day as the origin. For example:

> I have not taken a shower since Tuesday.

Your second sentence is not incorrect but it indicates that this 3 days period took place in the past. Both the origin day of this *3 days period* and the last day of this *3 days period* is happened in the past.

Comment: What about since three days ago?